# Is there a way to make try-catch statements in mex files?

Tags: matlab, error-handling, mex

I know that there is no built-in way to do try-catch statements in C, but has MATLAB facilitated any type of try-catch functionality for MEX files? I tried to use `Longjmp` and `Setjmp` in the way described in http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html, but I was not successful. Has anyone else figured out a way?

Comment: Been a while, but I seem to remember trying to run a mex dll through visual studio and then specifying matlab.exe as the program to start. Alternatively, you could attach to matlab.exe from VS and load up your compiled mex debug symbols.

Comment: Where does the "error" come from? C has no concept of exceptions, so what is it you want to catch, exactly?

Comment: @robguinness: Your URL has a typo: [http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html](http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html). Also, did you figure out why the `setjmp.h` method doesn't work for you?

Comment: @horchler: On SO you are free to fix these kinds of errors yourself (just click the edit link below the post). I've fixed the link in the post.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker: I realize that and you might be able to fix it with your higher reputation, but I cannot. I can only fix things if the edit consists of a minimum number of characters (10 in this case). It's annoying as a single character can make a huge difference and I'm an editor by nature. What else am I to do, put bogus characters in someone else's post to try to game the system?

Comment: @horchler: The minimum character limit is in place up to 2k reputation. For small but important edits one usually just adds a word (I capitalized MATLAB and MEX, for example). It's not about gaming the system, it's about improving the quality of the content :) See also [this thread on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81522/214749).

Answer (score 3):

You can [write your MEX-files in C++](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-c-source-mex-files.html#bq9pnqf-1) and use [the C++ exception handling](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/).

Comment: @robguinness: I know. However, in many settings it's possible for people to switch to C++ without much hassle, so I think the information is valuable in this context. Of course you are free not to accept my answer :) I'm not aware of any MEX-specific pure C error handling mechanisms.

Comment: This is true. I guess if there's no way to do it in C, I'll probably use your suggestion. Waiting to see if there are any other answers though...