# Is there a way to catch MEX-function segmentation-faults in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, try-catch, mex

When a Mex-function produces a segmentation-fault, a MATLAB System Error window pops-up and choosing `Attempt to Continue` leads to a lot of *useless* debugging information which is purred into the command window.

**Is it possible to catch these mex-exceptions in Matlab or at least to be able to process them later on?**

Unfortunately, following conventional try/catch won't work in this cases:

```
try
   myMex(input)
catch
   error('Mex failed')
end
```

Please note that I do not want to [catch the error inside the mex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190465/is-there-a-way-to-make-try-catch-statements-in-mex-files).

Comment: I would NOT do this.  There is a reason the system error suggests you quit MATLAB and not attempt to continue.  There is a pretty good chance you have corrupted memory.  Only use Attempt to Continue if you absolutely need to try to save some data.

Comment: Yes, there are good reasons not to do this. But I don't intend to use the results afterwards. I want to debug my C code and restarting matlab and reloading all data for every small change is just not practical.

Comment: Debug with a debugger.  Attach to MATLAB.   [Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27391300/2778484) (I use this method, but you can also tell `mex` to generate debugging info) or [Linux](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91741-how-do-i-debug-c-mex-files-under-unix)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code, you can compile the mex with debug mode (`-g` flag).
Then, depending on your platform, you can run the mex in debug mode (check out [Troubleshoot MEX-Files on MATLAB docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/troubleshoot-mex-files-1.html)).
If you are running in windows, you can use Visual Studio and select debug->Attach to Process and choose MATLAB. Then you can run your mex file, which will trigger an exception (and a breakpoint) in VS rather than MATLAB.

Comment: Yes, then I can interrupt in VS at the Matlab Breakpoint and do a lot of good debugging stuff. But if I end the Debugging in VS, the segmentation fault in Matlab is still evoked.